# Express.js not sending headers on dreamhost

Tags: node.js, express, cors, dreamhost

I am trying to access an api i built using express.js and am hosting on dreamhost but whenever i try to access it from another domain I run into CORS issues: "has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request."

I have tried using app.use(cors()) to no avail. I've even edited the .htaccess file.

When I check to see the headers that are being returned from my api, there are no lines showing the Access-Control-Allow-Origin information.

Code for express app:

```
const express = require('express');
const homeRouter= require('./routes/home.js');
const pmonboardingRouter= require('./routes/pmonboarding.js');
const resourceRouter= require('./routes/resource.js');
const userRouter= require('./routes/user.js');
const cors =require('cors');
// import helmet from 'helmet';

const app = express();

// app.use(helmet());


const port= process.env.SERVER_PORT || 3001;

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:true}))
app.use(cors({ origin: true }));

app.use('/resources',resourceRouter);
app.use('/pmonboarding',pmonboardingRouter);
app.use('/user',userRouter);
app.use('/',homeRouter);
```

Code for .htaccess file:

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "GET,POST,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "Content-Type"
```

Code for front end access:

```
fetch('<My api Domain>', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
})
```

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Frontend and Backend both running under same IP right?

Comment: nope different locations

Comment: try with app.use(cors({ origin: '*' }));

Comment: Tried that as well and still get the same results. It's weird that no headers are showing up. :/

Comment: Ive event tried manually going into specific paths and adding: res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); but that doesnt seem to work either :/

Comment: There's no way around it: browsers currently do not support redirects in responses to preflight requests. Can't you hit the target of the redirect instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Dont think So, Error looks 301. Can you try once with postman directly api.

Below one for reference for CROS issue,

```
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors({
    origin: 'https://www.domain.io'
}));

//or
app.use(cors({
    origin: ['https://www.domain.io', 'https://www.google.com/']
}));

//or
app.use(cors({
    origin: '*'
}));

//for origin with methods
app.use(cors({
     methods: ['GET','POST','DELETE','UPDATE','PUT','PATCH'],
     origin: '*'
}));

// maybe like this
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});
```

Comment: Just tried it... still nothing. Even restarted my server through ssh to make sure the changes were taking and still no cors headers are appearing

Comment: have you tried with postman?

Comment: the error looks 301 somthing, issue in api level its redirecting can share api code

Comment: OMG I just figured it out... it was an oversight on my part. I omitted the www. on the api call so it was forcing a redirect and causing headers not to show up. Thank you so much for your help!